# convert java code with RSA to c#

Tags: java, c#, encoding, rsa

I'm trying to convert this code:

```
 /**
 * Create a new PublicKey from encoded X.509 data
 */
public static PublicKey decodePublicKey(byte[] par0ArrayOfByte)
{
    try
    {
        X509EncodedKeySpec var1 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(par0ArrayOfByte);
        KeyFactory var2 = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return var2.generatePublic(var1);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException var3)
    {
        var3.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InvalidKeySpecException var4)
    {
        var4.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.err.println("Public key reconstitute failed!");
    return null;
}
```

into C# code but I cant find any working solution in C#

Full code you can find here:
[code](http://wklej.org/id/1398992/)

My last solution is

```
public PublicKey decodePublicKey(byte[] Data)
{
    X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2();
    x509.Import(Data);
    return x509.PublicKey;
}
```

but i get error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Cannot find the requested object.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a valid byte array containing the certificate binary data?

Comment: @Tarik In par0ArrayOfByte is only public key, probably encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X509EncodedKeySpec` is the `SubjectPublicKey` part of a certificate. So you probably need to decode this structure. You could look at BouncyCastle for C# and check out `Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.GetInstance(byte[])`

Comment: Sorry, only a partial answer that I did not have the time to verify myself.